How to add row group to a specific column in matrix ssrs?
Hello i have a case on ssrs, that i have to add a row group but only on specific column on the matrix,
Currently i have a row group based on column: emp_name & sku_kpi
And i have a column group based on column: detail(detail value is 1 & 2)
What make it difficult is the row group level is until sku kpi, but i have group the weight & achievement just on emp_name
My current result :

My expected result:

Is there a way to achieve my expected result ?

The values of weight and achievement are SUM of all items per employee?

Yes the value of weight and achievement are sum from all of the item per employees
